# useStateChange - Is there a more performant way to keep value updated without using useState / useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-hooks

So I became tired of using a bunch of `memo`, `useMemo`, and `useCallbacks` to keep my layered app responsive. Instead I built a react hook called `useStateChange` (I don't often need immediate updates provided by onChange).

```
function useStateChange(valuesInit) {
  const [values, valuesSet] = useState(valuesInit);
  useEffect(() => valuesSet(valuesInit), [valuesInit]);
  const onChange = useCallback(({ target: { value } }) => valuesSet(value), []);
  return [onChange, values, valuesSet];
}

function TestInput({ value0, onBlur }) {
  console.log("Test ran");
  const [onChange, value1] = useStateChange(value0);
  return (
    <>
      <h4>
        Value1:{" "}
        <input type="text" value={value1} onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} />
      </h4>
      <h5>Value1: {value1}</h5>
    </>
  );
}
```

Working example can be found at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-onblur-update-instead-of-onchange-bhqi5).

**Since this function will be used with nearly every input, is there any way to further improve the performance?**

I know people will nag about not over optimizing but this will become a critical component of my app and its better if its functioning at its best. If I had optimized with my `useStateChange` function, I wouldn't had my current performance problems...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `useState` initializes with the `valuesInit` but won't update if the `valuesInit` changes.

Comment: You can use uncontrolled components or store values in ref (`useRef`)

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice `valuesInit` was in the `deps`, you're right

Comment: @ArtemBalamutyuk Tried with uncontrolled but I can't initialize value. Haven't much experience with ref but looking into. Was previously taught not to use refs.

Comment: @SILENT You can initialize value with `defaultValue` attribute

Comment: @ArtemBalamutyuk If input value was to change elsewhere and I update `defaultValue`, would input update?

Comment: @SILENT No, only on mounting phase

Comment: @ArtemBalamutyuk I do need the input value to change if it was updated elsewhere. I tried using the ref to update via a `useEffect` but its not working.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. If you need to control input value elsewhere you need controlled component. The controlled component means that the view is controlled by the state. So every UI changes should update the state, input in your case

Comment: I couldn't find a reason why your custom hook improves performance, in your test case you just copied the parent value therefore it not renders the parent.

Comment: @DennisVash It improves my performance considerably. Previously, I had my parent component's state collect all the form inputs. On every `onChange` event, it would refresh my entire dynamic form. I had to use several `useMemo`,  etc to work around that. Instead, now I use `onBlur` to update my parent component's state. It still refreshes the form but now its only refreshes once I change to another element on the app, which is far less than `onChange`. I can still use `useMemo`, etc to further improve performance but its not really needed since the refresh rates have reduced significantly.